# AsyncTask closes when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This should be fairly simple. When I use AsyncTask to download a file, if you click on the screen the ui download progress goes away and it doesn't download correctly. How do I keep the ui progress and download on the screen even when the screen is pressed? Shoule be simple enough.

```
package com.cydeon.plasmamodz;

import com.stericson.RootTools.*;
import com.stericson.RootTools.exceptions.RootDeniedException;
import com.stericson.RootTools.execution.CommandCapture;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.cydeon.plasmamodz.R;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//Class for Boot Animation Blue Kindle
public class Boots extends Activity {

public static String TAG = "Boots";
Process process;

private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sURL) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL(sURL[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            //Shows 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            //Download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/plasma/boot/b..ootanimation.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                //Publish the Progress
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100/fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Installing. Please Wait";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()){
            RootTools.remount("/system", "rw");
            CommandCapture command = new CommandCapture(0, "su", "sh /sdcard/plasma/scripts/boots.sh");
                try {
                    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command).waitForFinish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RootDeniedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        } else {
            RootTools.offerBusyBox(Boots.this);
        }

    }
}

ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.boots);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.boot1);
    Button install = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAInstall);
    Button rtrn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAReturn);
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Boots.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading..." );
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    install.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
            downloadFile.execute("http:\\correspondingurl");


            }

        }
    );

    rtrn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    }



}
```

Comment: some code snippet will be good!

Comment: You might have a listener hooked up to th wrong view, but you will have to show some code, like where your task gets created.

Comment: My code? Ok, wait a second. Is it really code dependent. Isn't there just a method to keep the ui and diwnload when it's clicked?

Comment: Pretty much everything is "code dependent" since there are so many ways to do things

Comment: Where is your `getIntent()` coming from?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I thought it was something like, say, using setText on a text view. Pretty much universal...

Comment: Sorry. Let me edit my code real quick. I thought I removed those lines of codes. Give me a minute.. Ok, edited. :)

Comment: If you post the logcat it will actually help a lot

Comment: Ok. Is it not supposed to close when I click on the screen? I've seen it happen in other apps on the market...

Comment: Are you clicking on the `install` `Button` by any chance?

Comment: Yeah. When you click on that button it launches the download... Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I know and if you click on it again it tries to launch it again. Post the logcat

Comment: Ok. I'll have to reboot into Jellybean real quick and logcat it...

Answer (score 0):

If your just need to keep the ProgressDialog showing from pressed screen event. It's just simple add this code to your ProgressDialog.

```
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```